# Android: The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (MyBroadCastReceiver, String, int)

Tags: android, toast

i cant figure out the error, please help this is the code. i keep getting "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (MyBroadCastReceiver, String, int)"

```
    public class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadCastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent alarmIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(MyBroadCastReceiver.this, "Alarm worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

Should be

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try makeText(context, ...) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the activity to pass as the context.
Try

Toast.makeText(MyBroadCastReceiver.this.getActivity(),"Alarm worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();